# Instantiation of System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlContractConversionContext class

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, wsdl

For the case of a project requirement, I need to instantiate `WsdlContractConversionContext` which is not having a constructor for doing so.

Is there any work around to achieve this?

`WsdlContractConversionContext` is a member of the `System.ServiceModel.Description` namespace.

**Note:**
The requirement exactly is that, I am doing an implementation of `IWsdlExportExtension.ExportContract` and `IWsdlImportExtension.ImportContract`, and to unit test this implemetation I need the instance of `WsdlContractConversionContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two ways to do that: you can either use reflection to call the non-public constructor of the class (making sure you're passing appropriate parameters to it); or you can let WCF create it for you, and use it wherever you need. The `WsdlContractConversionContext` is passed as one of the parameters to either `IWsdlExportExtension.ExportContract` or an `IWsdlImportExtension.ImportContract`, so you'd need to implement one of the two interfaces (exporting is usually easier, since you won't need to fiddle with WSDL-consuming tools), and force the interface to be called (you may need to hit the service metadata endpoint for that).

The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/10/06/wcf-extensibility-wsdl-export-extension.aspx has an example of an implementation of a WSDL export extension.

*Update following edit in the question*: many parts of WCF are notoriously hard to be unit tested. If you can't use WCF itself to create the instance, the only alternative you have is to use reflection. To create an instance of the conversion context class you need an instance of a [ContractDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.contractdescription.aspx) (which you can create for your contract, but isn't easy), and a [PortType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.description.porttype.aspx), which is even harder. I'm afraid that unit testing your implementation of the WSDL export / import extension may not be worth the effort.

Comment: it is my mistake that I didn't mention the exact requirement in the question. I am just adding few more note to make it more clear with the question.